# Local Machine name is referenced instead of the remote machine

Tags: powershell, foreach

The script looks to be working but I am having a problem that I can not resolve.  When I run the script, it creates a text file but the propertie in the printer portion lookup is referencing my computer instead of the computer it is supposedly searching.

I have placed the script below because I don't know how it is still referencing my machine.  The text file that is saved does correctly save itself as the correct computer, but I have no faith in the script since it references my machine.

The portion where it references my computer in the text file is

```
The printer has been found!


Location      :
Name          : Upload to Doc
PrinterState  : 0
PrinterStatus : 3
ShareName     :
SystemName    : 1919WLB835  ← this is wrong, it should be the machine in the loop, not my machine
```

The piece that is pulling in the wrong computer name is

```
$Printer = gwmi Win32_Printer -Filter { name = "Upload to Doc" }
```

Here is the entire script:

```
        Import-Module PKI
        $DocvelocityDesktop = gwmi Win32_Product -Filter { Name like "%DocVelocity Desktop%" }
        $DocvelocityAddin = gwmi Win32_Product -Filter { Name = "Doc External Add-In for BytePro 1.0.16.0" }
        $ByteProVer = gwmi Win32_Product -Filter { Name = "BytePro Enterprise" }
        $Printer = gwmi Win32_Printer -Filter { name = "Upload to Doc" }
        $CertStore = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store "\\$ComputerName\TrustedPublisher", "LocalMachine"
        $CertStore.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]::ReadOnly)

        if ($Printer) {
            Write-Host The "Printer has been located"
            "The printer has been found!" | Out-File "c:\temp\$Computername.txt" -Append -Force
            $Printer | Out-File "c:\temp\$Computername.txt" -Append -Force
        } else {
            Write-Host "Fail.  Please install the printer cert for Capsilon"
            "Fail.  Please install the printer cert for Capsilon" | Out-File "c:\temp\$Computername.txt" -Append -Force
        }

        if ($DocvelocityDesktop) {
            Write-Host The "DocVelocity Desktop has been found."
            "The DocVelocity Desktop App was found!" | Out-File "c:\temp\$Computername.txt" -Append -Force
            $DocvelocityDesktop | Out-File "c:\temp\$Computername.txt" -Append -Force
        } else {
            Write-Host "Fail.  Please install the DocVelocity Desktop App"
            "Fail.  Please install the DocVelocity Desktop App" | Out-File "c:\temp\$Computername.txt" -Append -Force
        }

        if ($DocvelocityAddin) {
            Write-Host The "DocVelocity Addin has been found."
            "The DocVelocity Addin was found!" | Out-File "c:\temp\$Computername.txt" -Append -Force
            $DocvelocityAddin | Out-File "c:\temp\$Computername.txt" -Append -Force
        } else {
            Write-Host "Fail.  Please install the DocVelocity Addin"
            "Fail.  Please install the DocVelocity Addin" | Out-File "c:\temp\$Computername.txt" -Append -Force
        }
        if ($ByteProVer) {
            Write-Host The "BytePro has been found."
            "The BytePro App was found!" | Out-File "c:\temp\$Computername.txt" -Append -Force
            $ByteProVer.Version | Out-File "c:\temp\$Computername.txt" -Append -Force
        } else {
            Write-Host "Fail.  Please install Bytepro App"
            "Fail.  Please install the Bytepro App" | Out-File "c:\temp\$Computername.txt" -Append -Force
        }

        foreach ($Cert in $CertStore.Certificates) {
            if ($Cert.Subject -eq "CN=Capsilon Corporation, O=Capsilon Corporation, L=San Francisco, S=California, C=US" -and $Cert.Thumbprint -eq "B03318F507A687362261165ABD906277D122E9F1") {
                Write-Host "We have the cert for Capsilon Printer. "
                "The cert we need was found!" | Out-File "c:\temp\$Computername.txt" -Append -Force
                $Cert | Out-File "c:\temp\$Computername.txt" -Append -Force
            }
        }

        $CertStore.Close()
    } else {
        $Computername | Out-File c:\temp\dead_machines.txt -Force -Append
    }
}
```

Comment: You never specify a remote computer name when you do the WMI call

Comment: @EBGreen Is the data retrieved from the remote machine or the local machine on WMI calls?

Comment: I will be check this out.  Think I found the problem, thanks to EB.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309377(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Local machine unless you specify a remote machine using the -Computername parameter. How in the world would the cmdlet know which remote machine to query unless you told it?

Comment: Your "entire script" has a spurious `else` and closing curly bracket at its end.

Comment: Your are correct @EB.  I put the computername parameter in each gwmi call and it worked perfectly.  Thanks!